# Repository of the Mittler Rebbe's teachings translation

Tags: torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, translation, chabad, chassidic-rebbe

BH

Does anyone known a place of the Mittler Rebbe's works translated to English especially his commentary on Tanach?

Comment: I found this: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2329506/jewish/A-Judgment-of-Truth-and-Mercy.htm